# npm install phantom.js fails

Tags: node.js, npm, phantomjs, npm-install

When I run npm install, i get the following error I reinstalled node and that did not fix the problem. Not really sure where to go from here. It seems like it downloads a bunch of files and extracts them then quits unexpected when after saying receiving.

```
Install exited unexpectedly
npm ERR! Darwin 14.4.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! phantomjs@1.9.15 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs@1.9.15 install script 'node install.js'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project    with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs phantomjs
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Here is the package.json

```
{
   "name": "center-ui",
   "version": "1.1.43",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/ozone-development/ozp-center.git"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/ozone-development/ozp-center/blob/master   /README.md",
 "license": {
"type": "Apache-2.0",
"url": "https://spdx.org/licenses/Apache-2.0"
 },
 "bugs": "https://www.owfgoss.org/jira/browse/OZF",
"author": "",
 "description": "",
 "scripts": {
"start": "gulp dev",
"test": "./node_modules/karma/bin/karma start",
"build": "NODE_ENV=\"production\" gulp build",
"buildGhPages": "API_URL=\"https://www.owfgoss.org/ng/dev/mp\"   HUD_URL=\"http://ozone-development.github.io/ozp-hud/\" WEBTOP_URL=\"http://ozone-development.github.io/ozp-webtop/\" HELP_URL=\"http://ozone-development.github.io/ozp-hud/assets/PlaceholderUserGuide.pdf\" gulp build",
"deployGhPages": "npm run buildGhPages && gulp deploy",
"changelog": "gulp changelog",
"tarDistDate": "gulp tarDistDate",
"tarDistVersion": "gulp tarDistVersion"
   },
 "devDependencies": {
"babel-core": "^6.8.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
"babel-runtime": "^6.6.1",
"caroufredsel": "git://github.com/ozone-utils/caroufredsel",
"chai": "1.10.0",
"coffee-script": "1.8.0",
"conventional-changelog": "0.0.11",
"css-loader": "0.9.1",
"eslint-plugin-react": "^3.15.0",
"file-loader": "0.5.1",
"fs": "0.0.2",
"gulp": "3.9.0",
"gulp-bless": "~3.0.1",
"gulp-clean": "0.3.1",
"gulp-concat": "2.4.3",
"gulp-cssimport": "1.3.1",
"gulp-filter": "1.0.2",
"gulp-flatten": "0.0.2",
"gulp-gh-pages": "0.3.4",
"gulp-minify-css": "0.3.12",
"gulp-preprocess": "1.2.0",
"gulp-replace": "0.5.1",
"gulp-sass": "2.1.1",
"gulp-shell": "0.4.0",
"gulp-sourcemaps": "1.0.0",
"gulp-util": "2.2.20",
"inject-loader": "1.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
"jsx-loader": "0.12.2",
"karma": "0.12.31",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "0.1.7",
"karma-firefox-launcher": "0.1.4",
"karma-jasmine": "^0.3.6",
"karma-mocha": "0.1.10",
"karma-mocha-reporter": "^1.0.2",
"karma-phantomjs-launcher": "0.1.4",
"karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.3",
"karma-webpack": "1.5.0",
"mocha": "2.1.0",
"node-sass": "3.4.2",
"ozp-classification": "git://github.com/ozone-development/ozp-classification",
"raw-loader": "0.5.1",
"react-hot-loader": "0.5.0",
"react-proxy-loader": "0.3.2",
"script-loader": "0.6.1",
"sinon": "1.7.0",
"style-loader": "0.8.2",
"sweetalert": "git://github.com/ozone-utils/sweetalert",
"ubuntu-fontface": "git://github.com/ozone-utils/ubuntu-fontface",
"url-loader": "0.5.5",
"webpack": "1.12.11",
"webpack-dev-server": "1.14.1"
   },
   "dependencies": {
"babel-plugin-syntax-object-rest-spread": "^6.8.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes":"^6.8.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
"bootstrap-classify": "git://github.com/ozone-development/bootstrap-  classify#ozp-integ",
"bootstrap-sass": "git://github.com/ozone-development/bootstrap-sass",
"bootstrap-tour": "git://github.com/ozone-utils/bootstrap-tour",
"browser-pubsub": "^1.2.1",
"console-polyfill": "^0.2.2",
"es5-shim": "^4.0.5",
"eslint": "^1.10.3",
"eslint-loader": "^1.2.0",
"exports-loader": "0.6.2",
"humps": "git://github.com/domchristie/humps.git",
"icons": "git://github.com/ozone-development/ozp-icons",
"jquery": "^2.2.0",
"lodash-amd": "2.4.1",
"magnific-popup": "^0.9.9",
"marked": "^0.3.5",
"moment": "2.9.0",
"object-assign": "1.0.0",
"object-db": "^1.2.4",
"ozp-react-commons": "git://github.com/ozone-development/ozp-react-commons#master",
"react": "0.12.2",
"react-datepicker": "0.5.1",
"react-icon-rating": "0.2.0",
"react-input-placeholder": "1.0.0",
"react-radio-group": "1.0.0",
"react-router": "0.12.4",
"react-select-box": "git://github.com/ozone-development/react-select-box#master",
"reflux": "0.1.15",
"select2": "^3.5.1",
"spin.js": "2.0.2",
"tcomb-form": "0.2.1",
"tether": "0.6.5",
"w2ui": "git://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui#aa364dd39b4425265f40e92650fd669ddc3803fc"
  }
}
```

Comment: What kind of system have you tried to install it? You did `npm install -g phantomjs`, right (there is no `phantom.js`)?

Comment: i just did npm install with nothing following it in a github repo.

Comment: Then install PhantomJS globally and try again.

Comment: That worked!!!!

Comment: I got this error with an old version of mocha installed. Updated mocha and the error went away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
npm install -g phantomjs
```

PhantomJS needs to be installed globally and not just in the local folder.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's an issue with `install.js` which is located inside the `phantomjs` `node_modules` folder. What happens if you try to install a different version of the package?